# Mercurial - How to manage multiple modules

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial

I am working in a team using Subversion and we are considering switching to Mercurial.

We have multiple separate projects of unique code, as well as some code that is shared between some projects. For simplicity, imagine 2 projects, `SpaceGame` and `SeaGame`, that both use the code from `GraphicsEngine`. `GraphicsEngine` is being developed somewhat independently of the games. Lets say we need to update `SpaceGame` to revision 467 from a few months back; `SpaceGame` needs to go back to rev 467, and `GrpahicsEngine` needs to go back to the revision it was at when `SpaceGame` was at 467, `GraphicsEngine` cannot stay at the latest revision. The only way we can achieve this with Subversion is one big repository that we put all of our projects in (externals will not give us the behaviour we need). This creates a lot of problems for our team though; the repo is huge, barely anyone wants to do a full checkout of it, they only checkout the projects they need.

How would one handle this situation with Mercurial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a use case for [Mercurial subrepositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository).

This means that you can put `GraphicsEngine` as a subrepository into `SpaceGame`.
*(or if you follow [the recommended structure](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository#Use_a_thin_shell_repository_to_manage_your_subrepositories), create a thin "wrapper" repo that contains both `GraphicsEngine` and `SpaceGame` and subrepositories)*

The way subrepositories work, `SpaceGame` doesn't always contain the most recent version of `GraphicsEngine`...it points to a certain fixed revision, and if `GraphicsEngine` is updated in the meantime, `SpaceGame` does **not** get these changes automatically...you have to do an explicit update to get them.
This means that `SpaceGame` will never break unexpectedly because of someone else's changes to `GraphicsEngine`.

This also means *(and this is what you asked about)* that when you update `SpaceGame` "to revision 467 from a few months back", the `GraphicsEngine` subrepository [is automatically updated to the revision that it was at when `SpaceGame` was at 467](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository#Synchronizing_in_subrepositories).

---

**EDIT:**

No, `GraphicsEngine` is still a separate repository and not "owned" by anyone.
If you use it as a sub-repository, it is just "linked" from the parent repositories (and it can be linked from more than one parent repository). It still stays a separate repository.

With subrepositories, something like this is possible:

```
GraphicsEngine      // main GraphicsEngine repo, current revision: 300

SpaceGame           // main SpaceGame repo
  └ GraphicsEngine  // GraphicsEngine subrepo, current revision: 265

SeaGame             // main SeaGame repo
  └ GraphicsEngine  // GraphicsEngine subrepo, current revision: 241
```

Both `SpaceGame` and `SeaGame` have a `GraphicsEngine` subrepo each.
Each subrepo "points" to a certain revision of `GraphicsEngine` (265 and 241 in my example).
Development in `GraphicsEngine` continues (`GraphicsEngine` is at rev 300), but the most recent changes aren't visible in `SpaceGame` and `SeaGame` because they both point to older `GraphicsEngine` revisions.

Answer (score 1):

**Just note**: Christian is right, but instead of Subrepo I'll suggest to at least try [GuestRepo](https://bitbucket.org/selinc/guestrepo), created as answer on some subrepos limitations and shortcomings.

BTW:

> externals will not give us the behaviour we need

is just wrong answer, result of bad research. You **can** use svn:externals, by two different ways, and both (with some handwork) will give you needed results

**Subrepo-like way**

GraphicsEngine linked as externals with **fixed revision** in definition. Every time, when you have and have to use more fresh revision in "SuperRepository" (repository with externals), you must to **update** externals definition and **commit parent** project. With such hard-linking Superrepo always have oredefined pair of revisions for parent-externals.

**Free linking, manual update of externals in time-back machine**

If you don't want to worry about monitoring of externals update in scenario 1 ( in the case of *singe externals* update of definition can be automated with hook), you can use externals, linked to HEAD of GraphicsEngine (don't use revision in definition) for the cost of manual (or by *some script*) update of directory, which contain external data. I'm too lazy to write it, so - only write here workflow

With HEAD-linking, for revision N of main repo in the past, externals must be at the state of revision M, which is latest revision of linked repo at the time of revision N. Fortunately, svn can use date-spefifications (different forms) as parameter of -r option. You have only identify date-time of commit N and update externals dir (get "Mixed revisions working copy")

`svn log -q -r N` in main repo will give something like

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r34 | lazybadger | 2012-03-24 12:28:12 +0600 (Сб, 24 мар 2012)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Just remember date field "2012-03-24 12:28:12 +0600" for now.

`svn help up` confirms, what we can use date as revision specifier

```
-r [--revision] ARG      : ARG (some commands also take ARG1:ARG2 range)
                             A revision argument can be one of:
                             ...       
                                '{' DATE '}'
                             ...
```

and in [SVN-Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html), "Revision Dates" chapter, we'll find correct format for our (date-time-TZ) case

```
...
$ svn checkout -r {"2006-02-17 15:30 +0230"}
...
$ svn checkout -r {2006-02-17T15:30-04:00}
...
$ svn checkout -r {20060217T1530-0500}
```

First format is best choice for us (because we already have it from svn log), thus - we can in WC with externals (still not synced with main revision)

```
cd EXTERNAL-DIR
svn up -r {"2012-03-24 12:28:12 +0600"}
```

and get external at the same state, as it was in the the past, when main revision (in my sample) was 34

**PS**: `svn log ...| gawk {...}` can easy extract and store date-time of base revision